# MySQL - Delete from multiple tables using a UNION?

Tags: mysql

I have tables all with the same columns and have divided them up this way to keep them small.

e.g.
Tables - cpus, gfxcards, monitors.
Columns - titleId, categoryId, name.

What I'm trying to do is similar to this

```
SELECT * FROM cpus
UNION
SELECT * FROM gfxcards;
DELETE FROM test WHERE (titleId,categoryId) IN ((2,0));
```

Is there a way to do this or do I have to use transactions to avoid multiple delete queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, nevermind. I worked out the query I was looking for. e.g. To delete CPUs with IDs 4,7 from 'cpus' table and monitors with IDs 105,106 from 'monitors' table, the following single query works.

```sql
DELETE
c, m FROM cpus c, monitors m
WHERE
(c.titleId,c.categoryId) IN ( (4,0), (7,0) )
AND
(m.titleId,m.categoryId) IN ( (105,3), (106,3) );
```

But thanks for the replies =)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a multiple-table delete statement with join syntax. It could be like this:

```
delete from cpus, gfxcards using cpus, gfxcards where cpus.titleId = gfxcards.categoryId;
```

This is if the tables are related. Otherwise, you can use a stored procedure or function.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does support deletes from multiple tables at the same time.  However, why not just do three deletes?

```
delete from cpus where titleId = 2 and categoryId = 0;
delete from monitors where titleId = 2 and categoryId = 0;
delete from gfxcards where titleId = 2 and categoryId = 0;
```

If you need for these to be atomic, then wrap these in a single transaction.  The deletions will then all take place when the transaction commits.

By the way, this is one reason why you don't want such parallel tables.  You should really have a single table with a type column specifying the object.

Comment: But if I put all of these tables into a single table and say the tables could have been a small size of 500,000 records instead of one big 1,500,000, wouldn't MySQL search the smaller table faster?

The reason I am splitting them into separate tables, apart from keeping them small, is also because not all categories will be used at any time.

Comment: @Ken . . . Use indexes, and the search time should be pretty much the same for 500k versus 1500k records.  If you want to optimize for categories, you can make `categoryID` part of the primary key or use it for a partitioning scheme.

Comment: I think that using multiple statements does not return the overall affected rows. Only the affected rows of the last statement are returned.